# Passing a string array to templated search function

Tags: c++, arrays, string, templates

In the code below, I'm trying to search a string array I pass to a template function for a particular string, but I get the error "no matching function for call to `arraySearch". The previous two function calls for the int array and double array work fine, seems like I'm just missing come detail for dealing with the string array, and I can't figure out what it is. At any rate, it must be an array (no vectors). Any help would be very appreciated!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
bool arraySearch(T array[], int size, T thing)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
          if(array[i] == thing)
          return true;
     }

     return false;
}         

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 12;
    int intArray[] = {14, 3, 6, 76, 34, 22, 21, 54, 33, 23, 76, 234};
    cout << "The element was found: " << arraySearch(intArray, SIZE, 23) << endl;

    double doubleArray[] = {34.5, 65.56, 11.1, 45.4, 87.5, 98.3, 23.6, 15.5, 3.3, 5.44, 54.3, 99.9};
    cout << "The element was found: " << arraySearch(doubleArray, SIZE, 23.6) << endl;

    string stringArray[] = {"cool", "bug", "master", "katze", "republic", "randolph", "watermelon", "igloo", "sardine", "cream", "yellow", "rubber"};
    cout << "The element was found: " << arraySearch(stringArray, SIZE, "cool") << endl;

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Templates together with unsafe C-style arrays? Come on...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Could you say a bit more?

Comment: What I mean is, why don't you use proper C++ containers such as `std::array` or `std::vector`, rather than `T[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say:

```
cout << "The element was found: " << arraySearch(stringArray, SIZE, std::string("cool")) << endl;
```

The problem is that `"cool"` is not an instance of `T` when the the template is instantiated with `T` as `std::string`.  In C++, string literals are C char arrays, not `std::string`.

Also, you could simply use `std::find` from `<algorithm>` to achieve the same effect as the code you posted.  `std::find` can work with C-arrays and pointers as well as C++ iterators.

```
std::string* res = std::find(stringArray, stringArray + sizeof(stringArray) / sizeof(std::string), "cool");
```

Comment: Nice! Your explanation made sense.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `T` is deduced to be `std::string` from the first argument, and `const char*` from the second argument.

Therefore, the compiler does not know which one to pick. Try doing:

```
arraySearch(stringArray, SIZE, std::string("cool"))
```

Or, alternatively, let the function template accept arguments of different type:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
bool arraySearch(T array[], int size, U thing)
```

This won't require constructing an `std::string` object explicitly:

```
arraySearch(stringArray, SIZE, "cool")
```

If you decide to preceed this way, you may want to further SFINAE-constrain your function template so that it accepts only types that are equality-comparable:

```
template<typename T, typename U, 
         decltype(declval<T>() == declval<U>())* = nullptr>
bool arraySearch(T array[], int size, U thing)
```